# Adjust width and height on page in landscape mode

Tags: width, landscape, height

I'm writing a business plan using the [business plan theme from elsamuko](https://github.com/elsamuko/business_plan_template). The last part is a financial plan which is added on an empty page in landscape mode. I want to add just a simple pdf output to a page in landscape mode. My MWE looks like this :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=8.3in, paperheight=11.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, array}
\usepackage{hyperref, bookmark}
\usepackage{packages/fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}

\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in

\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt

\rhead{\includegraphics{images/letterhead_right_en.eps}}
\lhead{\includegraphics{images/letterhead_left.eps}}
\rfoot{Draft}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{This document is signed}


\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{landscape}
        \subsection{Finanzplan}
        \begin{figure}[!h]
            \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{finanzplan_default.pdf}
        \end{figure}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The finanzplan_default.pdf can be downloaded from [here](https://we.tl/t-sHXhwZJrZn)

The problem is that instead of one empty styled page in landscape mode with the subsection in the header and the pdf output, a second page in landscape mode is added with the standard page style of the business template. This is due to a warning that the figure is too large for the page size. How can I optimize the pageheight and pagewidth for the page in landscape mode so the pdf page is added to the first (empty styled) page? Please keep in mind, that there are several other pages where the standard page adjustments defined by geometry are needed!

If possible, I would like to avoid adding the table manually in a table environment.
[image: wide screenshot of the pdf output after the compilation]

Comment: Any news? Is none of the answers helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont have code for You: I tried do download the example plan (two times) and one commercial page was opened.

But I can propose two solutions:

1. You can, for your plan page only, define a new geometry page, larger
   and then use \restoregeometry command to return to yours previous
   definition.
2. You can save your pdf for plan page and then include in your document
   this one like a picture, with \includegraphics[scale=.9]{plan.pdf}. If scale=0.9 is not sufficient, you try scale=0.8.

Answer (score 0):

You declare with

```
\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{finanzplan_default.pdf}
```

that image had to be 20% wider from available space on page. Using

```
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{finanzplan_default.pdf}
```

should resolve your problem.

- Because image is to big that can be fit on page, it is moved to the end of landscape environment
- In image size you should consider space for section title
- Since image of table hasn't caption and you like that it be immediately after sub section title, I suggest you to remove float `figure` and determined figure size as it is done in MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,
            margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}      % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={My title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Author},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={keywords}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{image-right}%\includegraphics{images/letterhead_right_en.eps}}
\lhead{image.left}%\includegraphics{images/letterhead_left.eps}}
\rfoot{Draft}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\lfoot{This document is signed}


\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\subsection{Finanzplan}
        
\includegraphics[height=0.95\textwidth, % <---
                 width=\linewidth]      % <---
                {example-image-duck}% insert your real image ...                
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I reorganize a wee bit of package loading (`hyperref` had to be loaded last) and remove all page size definitions outside from `geometry` options (they only rewrite `geometry` settings).